# compact operator have infinite dimension null space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a compact operator of infinite dimensional separable Banach space $X$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Given that $T$ is block lower triangular, and each row is not zero. Is the null space always infinite dimensional?

Here is what I thought: We know that $T$ must have nonzero null space, so after row operation must have at least one row is all zero. Assume there are only finite row are all zero. Then remove them to construct operator $T'$.  That is, $T$ is not surjective. Now $T'$ is a linear operator from $X$ to a subspace of $X$. Since $T$ is still compact in the subspace, there must be one more zero row in $T'$, contradiction.

The above argument sounds valid but something is weird. Because I don't think all compact operator have infinite dimensional null space.

Comment: What is a "Banach space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$"?

Comment: vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, with norm defined $||a||=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}2^{-i}$

Comment: That looks like something $2$-adic, but the $2$-adic integers aren't a field. Do you mean a Banach space over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ or a Banach module over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is Banach module or 2-adic, I will say $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ with some norm define above. I am not sure if this space is complete or not

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z}_2$ denotes the $2$-adic integers, there is no vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ according to the terminologies I'm acquainted with, since vector spaces are modules over fields (or, in the wider sense, over skew fields, aka division rings, aka division algebras). Thus for a vector space, it would have to be a vector space over the $2$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_2$. If $\mathbb{Z}_2$ denotes $\mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z})$, what is a norm on such a space?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{2}=\{0,1\}$, which is a field with characteristic 2.  Norm for $X$ has been defined above.

Comment: I meant generically. What properties must a function have to be a norm on a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$? (I haven't yet encountered normed vector spaces over any field that isn't a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ or some $\mathbb{Q}_p$.)

Comment: Let it be $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ then, although I am not sure. Will the result depends on the field?